# iOS SDK for launching SMS based support chat from hyperlinked phone number?

Tags: ios, safari, chat

[image]

When I search for my ISPs phone number from an iPhone running iOS 13.5, I am presented with a hyperlinked phone number.  When I tap on this phone number I receive a native iOS menu that allows selecting a live chat vs a call.  Launching the live chat starts a chat session with their support team in iMessage. Additionally it shows this vendor as “Verified”.

How is this accomplished? Where is the documentation about this API? How do I become a verified vendor? Is this a special format in the hyperlink? I am aware of

```
href=“tel://...”
```

But is there some new URL format for trigging a native live chat dialogue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer it’s called apple business chat https://developer.apple.com/business-chat/